# "errorMessage": "lambda_handler() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql

This code works correctly in my machine but getting error in AWS Lambda:

```py
import pymysql

dbhost = 'database.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
dbuser = 'admin'
dbpass = 'admin123'
dbname = 'classicmodels'
connection = pymysql.connect(host=dbhost, user=dbuser, password=dbpass, database=dbname)

def lambda_handler():
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Persons')
  rows = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in rows:
    print ("{0} {1} {2}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))

lambda_handler()
```

```
{
"errorMessage": "lambda_handler() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given",
"errorType": "TypeError",
"requestId": "fb790715-91f1-4f7a-961f-b83485d23b68",
"stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py\", line 149, in handle_event_request\n    response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)\n"
]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: fb790715-91f1-4f7a-961f-b83485d23b68 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] TypeError: lambda_handler() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 149, in handle_event_request
response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)END RequestId: fb790715-91f1-4f7a-961f-b83485d23b68
REPORT RequestId: fb790715-91f1-4f7a-961f-b83485d23b68  Duration: 1.07 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB
```

Comment: The function name might be conflicting . Try changing the function name `lambda_handler()` to something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do *not* call the handler:

```py
lambda_handler()
```

The AWS Lambda service will call the handler when the function is invoked.

Also, the Lambda function should be defined as:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

The `event` will contain information about what triggered the event and the `context` will contain information about the Lambda deployment environment.

Comment: after change getting below result

`{
  "errorMessage": "lambda_handler() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "f25b142f-d122-4c3b-9e55-28796af713a9",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py\", line 149, in handle_event_request\n    response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)\n"
  ]
}`

Comment: Function Logs
START RequestId: f25b142f-d122-4c3b-9e55-28796af713a9 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] TypeError: lambda_handler() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 149, in handle_event_request
    response = request_handler(event, lambda_context)END RequestId: f25b142f-d122-4c3b-9e55-28796af713a9
REPORT RequestId: f25b142f-d122-4c3b-9e55-28796af713a9 Duration: 1.06 ms Billed Duration: 2 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB

Comment: Did you remove the `lambda_handler()` line and modify the `def lambda_handler():` line to `def lambda_handler(event, context):`? If so, please add your updated code to the bottom of your Question.

Comment: thanks @John Rotenstein
I deleted old function and created new as per above given suggestion.
It is working now